# Camunda 1 to n - modify multi instance subprocess at runtime

Tags: bpmn, business-process-management, camunda

I have a specific requirement in 1 to n problem. If I have groups and in each group there are multiple items, then I can give these groups to multi instance subprocess.

If a group is not completed because of an issue in one item, then I want to remove that item out of that group and finish processing that group. Is this addressed in 1 to n problem. If yes, what is the solution for this?

Comment: It should be solvable by using a custom closing condition, I can help you with a test case if you have some more input. It's always helpful if you could provide your process model, your test code and an overview what you already tried.